# No MySQLi Connection despite it is working

Tags: php, fuelphp

**Pre-requisite**

- OS Elementary OS Luna (Ubuntu 12.02 LTS)
- Installed apache2 w/ PHP
- Installed mysqli extension
- MariaDB 10.0.8

**Scenario**

- Installed FuelPHP 1.7.1 on /var/www/projectname.local
- setup vhost file [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nrpjBqHv)
- setup db.php on development config folder [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BSk0KdGW)
- changed the project folder chown to www-data:www-data
- changed the project folder chmod to 777 for editing in IDE

**Error**

- application error "No MySQLi Connection"

**Note**

- phpmyadmin is working (it requires mysqli to work)

**What I Did**

- re-create the database and set new user/password
- check if I am editing the right folder (i.e: if the application is set to check the development/testing/staging/production configuration). It is set to development.
- check error log for specific error in fuel php log files (nothing found helpful)
- changed the type => "mysql" from "mysqli" ... "Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ Error ]:" is shown in the browser.

**My Question**

- Determine what specific error (FuelPHP only display No Mysqli connection). Like wrong username/password, wrong port etc ...

Comment: What happens if you change ` 'type'            => 'mysqli',` to ` 'type'            => 'mysql',` ?

Comment: out of question query.....why do u have `777` chmod instead of `755`?? :o

Comment: @NoobEditor since the project folder is located on the /var/www (under root ownership) I can't edit it using Netbeans IDE. I can't name it to my user/group since apache2 needs to write log files. So I just chmod it to 777.

Comment: @Brainscrewer a blank error. "Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ Error ]:"

Answer (score 0):

Never thought that error reporting in Fuel is **that** BAD.

As a quick workaround you can either patch that pathetic line

```
throw new \Database_Exception('No MySQLi Connection', 0);
```

with

```
throw new \Database_Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), 0);
```

or change your driver to PDO.

Comment: I tried mysqli_connect_error() "Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ Error ]:". Changing to pdo gave me "Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ Error ]:
invalid data source name"

Comment: to change a driver is NOT just to change three letters in config.

Comment: You want me to switch my DB from MariaDB to postgress?